# Using seperate activities as forms, switching between them?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments

I have multiple activities that each contain different forms with user input (edittext, spinners, switches, etc). I want to be able to switch between the forms/"windows" freely. I experimented with the navigation drawer concepts but I can't get the activities adapted to work as fragments. Ideally, I'd love to use a similar design to the navigation drawer if possible. What's the best way to accomplish this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android provides some really Designs to make use simple as simple.. These two are some Design Patterns that will satisfy your requirements.

**1.SwipeTabs** (BEST to your Requirement)[image: Swipe Tab]

**2.[Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)** (Good Design)

[image: Navigation Drawer]

U have awesome tutorials to help u go in.

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/ (Swipe tabs)
http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/ (Navigation Drawer).

Hope u got some help. :)

Comment: These both look great, thanks! The only issue is that they require fragments, but I've already written all of the parts as activities. How can I adapt them to fragments?

Comment: I highly recommend you switch to fragments; http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Yep, I was able to switch my activities over using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGXenxtDEGQ